# Clipboard sharing broken in OS X Sierra

Tags: osx, clipboard

Just upgraded to Sierra, and if I try to copy or paste text, nothing goes through. Has anyone else experienced this problem? Any way to debug the prolem?

Apparently Sierra [also broke](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/543) copy/paste in Tmux, which relies on `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`.

This is with Emacs (25.1.1), which I always install with `brew`:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-glib --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick
```

Comment: MacOS Sierra is just too new -- Emacs 25 was not designed to be compatible with a version of OS X that was not publicly released during the Emacs 25 development cycle.  Consider submitting a bug report and updating your question to reflect the tracking link.  If the Emacs team is able to address the issue, then follow-up with an answer/response in a few days/weeks/months.

Comment: Is the version distributed via emacsformacos.com also broken?

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard interaction works fine for me on  Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5 and Emacs 25.2.1

Here are my settings:

`; Merge system's and Emacs' clipboard
(setq select-enable-clipboard t)
;; Save whatever’s in the current (system) clipboard before
;; replacing it with the Emacs’ text.
;; https://github.com/dakrone/eos/blob/master/eos.org
(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)
(defun clipboard-on ()
    (interactive)
    (setq interprogram-cut-function 'paste-to-osx)
    (setq interprogram-paste-function 'copy-from-osx))
  (defun clipboard-off ()
    (interactive)
    (setq interprogram-cut-function 'gui-select-text)
    (setq interprogram-paste-function 'gui-selection-value))
  (global-set-key (kbd "S-p") 'clipboard-on)
  (global-set-key (kbd "S-y") 'clipboard-off)`